# Java serialisation and dealing with objects

Tags: java, class, serialization

I'm using the code below, to get data from a file saved on my desktop to input into the game that I'm making.

```
try {
    FileInputStream saves = new FileInputStream("/Users/Prodigy958/Desktop/Hack_exeSaves.ser");
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(saves);
    test = (player) in.readObject();
    in.close();
    saves.close();
} catch(IOException error) {
    error.printStackTrace();
    return;
} catch(ClassNotFoundException error) {
    error.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

There is also the section which takes the player object and inputs it into a file.

```
player realPlayer = new player();
realPlayer.name = newName;
realPlayer.gender = newGender;
realPlayer.hasStarted = false;
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/Users/Prodigy958/Desktop/Hack_exeSaves.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    out.writeObject(realPlayer);
    out.close();
    fileOut.close();
} catch(IOException i) {
    i.printStackTrace();
}
```

The issue that I am having is that if you save more than one player data onto the file, it calls up errors because it takes all the data and turns it into one player object. Do you know an easy way I would be able to split up the data? I have thought about using multiple files to store each different object's data. I have also though about taking out the data and splitting it up into separate objects, and then working from there, however I don't know where to start on the second one.

Comment: What about serializing a Set or a HashMap of players?

Comment: @BCartolo what would that do? The issue is, that there aren't always going to be multiple players on the file.

Comment: And Set of size 1 does not suit you because.....?

Comment: @whitesite because i need to be able to save more than one players data onto it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already suggested, use a Serializable implementation of [java.util.Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). (Most of the java.util collections--such as [java.util.ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [java.util.HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)--are Serializable.) A collection of 0 or 1 elements shouldn't bother you (it's not relevant to the serialization of the collection) unless your game has other business requirements that care, but... in that case, that's far beyond the scope of this question, and for you to handle on your own.